# playing audio in an iphone game

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am developing an iphone game app. I want to play different audios(*.mp3) in main menu and  each different level. I have tried to use AVAudioPlayer and I got some error while changing the audios. So what do you suggest me to use?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at this https://github.com/nicklockwood/SoundManager. Very good helper class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vignesh.The example works perfectly fine but I believe I found something that might want to consider to modify your code.
 

    static SoundManager *sharedManager = nil;
    
    + (SoundManager *)sharedManager
    {
     if (sharedManager == nil)
     {
      sharedManager = [[self alloc] init];
     }
     return sharedManager;
    }
Code should be modified like this. So everytime SoundManager created it won't create again.
Thanks

Comment: @Cemsi07. It is not my code!. I have just given the link to someone else code :)